# function associated with samplerBuffer in Glsl

Tags: graphics, glsl, shader, vulkan

I am writing a Compute shader using the following:

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 1) uniform highp samplerBuffer  u_texelBuffer;
```

and trying to fetch by using the following command

```
void main(void)
{
  highp vec4 result_color;

  result_color = texelFetch(u_texelBuffer, 6);
}
```

Is there any other function I can use instead of `texelFetch`. Because `texelFetch` results in pagefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer textures can only be accessed via the `texelFetch` family of functions. If you are getting page faults, odds are good it is because you have failed to do something. Use Vulkan validation layers to find out what you did wrong.

Comment: tried validation layer. Found no issues with validation, It gives page faults on one device and on other device it doesn't result in page faults @https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas